# sharepoint designer can not display the item!

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

The scenario that lead to this error was:
1. I created a custom activity, it worked.
2. Then I wanted to change some names of properties, after deploying, this happened

Is there anyway to remove some STEPS from the sharepoint designer workflow by hand, so that it loads correctly again??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still can access the WF from "All Files" in SPD you could edit the .xoml file.

Edit: Btw when publishing custom activities sometimes SPD freaks out due to its cache. Here is a [blog post](http://mugdhasabnis.blogspot.com/2011/10/sharepoint-designer-workflow-keeps.html) for the steps to clear it. (It does no damage in clearing this cache, its on your local computer)

Comment: +1 on this statement. You should be able to figure out the XOML and locate the activities and remove them.